# Not getting my parameter from the body of the request

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, angular-resource

I try and hit my API Controller which I'm able to make it there.  However the method is not getting my parameter from the body of the request. I know this is something small.

I've tried moving the service around adding parameters in many different ways. Nothing so far seems to work.

Key Things to Note

This is a MVC 4 application if that helps.  I believe it's something in the angular syntax or possibly the controller attributes.

I'm using a HTTPPost.

**Service**

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var rmdsnewServices = angular.module('rmdsnewServices', ['ngResource']);

rmdsnewServices.factory('rmds', ['$resource',
  function ($resource) {
      return {
          rmdnewly: $resource('/api/rmd/', {}, {
              query: {
                  method: 'GET', params: {}, url: '/api/rmd/getNewly/', isArray: false,
                  transformResponse: function (data) { return { list: angular.fromJson(data) } }
              }
          }),

          rmdsave: $resource('/api/rmd/AddRMD/:newrmd', { newrmd: '@newrmd' }, {
              save: {

                  method: 'POST', params: { newrmd: '@newrmd' }

              }

          })



      };
  }]);
})();
```

**API Controller**

```
[Route("api/rmd/AddRMD")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddRMD([FromBody]string newrmd)
    {
        var rmd = newrmd;

        bool result;
        //result = rs.AddRMD(newrmd);
        result = true;
        if (result)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ExpectationFailed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: IINM you're sending an (JSON) object, however,  the API is expecting a "simple" `string`.  Check the payload the browser sends to verify what is actually being POSTed to your endpoint. Hth...

Comment: try, in your api, to change the signature to: public HttpResponseMessage AddRMD(string newrmd)

Comment: @AmmarHamidou If I take off the [FromBody] I'm not hitting the method anymore.  I get a 404 not found.

Comment: @EdSF I'm using the example found in this link. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Yep. if you look at the sample where it uses `[FromBody] string name` you can see what the API expects displayed in the _"example client request"_ - you can see it's just a `string` ("Alice"), vs what you're sending via Angular `{ newrmd: '@newrmd' }` (json object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller action expects a string. 
Also, your $resource doesn't need to send the :param on the url:

```
                      rmdsave: $resource('/api/rmd/AddRMD/', { }, {
                      save: {
                          method: 'POST'
                      }
                  })
```

Then sending simply a string, will hit your controller:

```
        angular.module('rmdsnewServices').controller('MyController', ['rmds', function (rmds) {
        this.click = function() {
            rmds.rmdsave.save("'asd'");
        }
    }]);
```

To send an object instead of the string:

```
rmds.rmdsave.save({Name:"someName"});



  public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class rmdController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("api/rmd/AddRMD")]
        public HttpResponseMessage SomePath([FromBody] Test newrmd)
        { ...
```

Comment: Would this be the same setup if I want to send Json?

Comment: Yes, except that your Web API controller would be getting a Model instead of string and the framework would do the data-binding for you. rmds.rmdsave.save({}) sends an object

Comment: How does that change my save on my api?